# php associative array count

Tags: php, arrays, count, associative-array

I would like to count the occurances of data in a associative array i have. Here is the output of my array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [url] => http://test.com [date] => 14-04-2014 [time] => 16:06:09 ) [1] => Array ( [url] => Direct [date] => 14-04-2014 [time] => 16:06:37 ) [2] => Array ( [url] => http://test.com [date] => 15-04-2014 [time] => 08:10:43 ) [3] => Array ( [url] => http://test.com [date] => 15-04-2014 [time] => 08:50:02 ) [4] => Array ( [url] => http://test.com [date] => 15-04-2014 [time] => 08:50:06 ) [5] => Array ( [url] => http://test.com [date] => 15-04-2014 [time] => 08:50:09 ) )
```

I then loop through the results like this:

```
foreach ($refs as $key => $va){

echo $va['date'];   

}
```

I would like to count the dates that are the same.

So the above would produce:

```
14-04-2014 = 2
15-04-2014 = 3
```

What is the best approach to do this? I  have tried using `array_count_values` but cant seem to get this to work with an associative array. I get the following error:

```
Warning: array_count_values() [FUNCTION.ARRAY-COUNT-VALUES]: Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `array_map` to convert the array first.

```
$result = array_count_values(array_map(function ($var) {
  return $var['date'];
}, $refs));
```

For php < 5.3:

```
$dates = array();

foreach ($refs as $ref) {
  $dates[] = $ref['date'];
}

$result = array_count_values($dates);
```

You could also not use `array_count_values` and do the counting in the loop directly.

Comment: this throws out: unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'

Comment: @danyo If your php version is < 5.3, then you can't use anonymous function. You could either create a function or just use a loop to collect the data.